# FullCalendar problem (you could help without knowledge of FullCalendar)

Tags: javascript, dom, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I have a calendar with FullCalendar v6, I want to remove some time slots (it works) but the problem is that if I have events after this time slot, when I render the calendar, due to the fact that the event is related with the column in the DOM instead of the row, it gets the initial position of the slot. Business hours just paints the calendar, but the slots will show. If I press F12 or I resize the window it fits on the new position, but it doesn´t work with resizeTo() or anything in JS. Any idea? My objective is to make visible just the hours with events, I don't care making like this or using any other method (tried visiblRange, businessHours...).

I tried to get the slots hidden and the events repositioned, but events won't reposition. Edit: When you resize the browser it repositions but when I use resizeTo, scaleX, etc... It doesn't.

**Edit:** Do you know what's the function that reposition the events? Or when it's triggered?

```js
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
  slotDuration: '00:30:00',
});

let newEvent = {
  title: 'Nuevo evento',
  start: '2023-04-20T09:00:00',
  end: '2023-04-20T10:00:00',
  allDay: false
};

let newEvent2 = {
  title: 'Nuevo evento 2',
  start: '2023-04-20T14:00:00',
  end: '2023-04-20T15:00:00',
  allDay: false
}

calendar.render()
document.querySelector('[data-time="11:00:00"]').parentElement.style.display = "none";
var el = document.querySelector('[data-time="11:30:00"]');
el.parentElement.style.display = "none" //Tryied .remove()
calendar.addEvent(newEvent);
calendar.addEvent(newEvent2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.5/index.global.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>


<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan if you run code you will see that the event starts at 2 but in the left you see its positioned at 3pm and if you resize it will get its position.

Comment: How about disabling the slot instead? I would be confused if my calendar missed an hour in the middle

Comment: Explain it to my boss, lol @mplungjan, yeah, I get you, kind of confusing... Thanks! The fact is that if we have just two events,  one at 8 am and the other at 6pm we have a lot of white space... I will think about it, thanks mate. Maybe reducing the height of the empty slots? But same problem there I supose...

Comment: You will not be able to do this like this. You have TWO different containers. the events are in a completely different container and not row based.
I tried this, but that is not what you want either `document.querySelectorAll('[data-time^="11"]').forEach(el => el.parentElement.style.visibility = "hidden")`
I suggest you open an issue here: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues

Comment: `The fact is that if we have just two events, one at 8 am and the other at 6pm`...is that consistently what happens, or just an example? I'm just thinking, if you used a much larger [slot Duration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotDuration) that would save a lot of space.

Comment: It's just an example, I'm parsing an ajax response of an API, depending on the response (based on the center we are working with) could be one event, two or 7 (that can last 30mins, 1:30, 2:30...). That's why I chose a 30 mins slot duration. @ADyson

Comment: `Do you know what's the function that reposition the events`...it would be `calendar.render()`. But it will try to reposition the events against where it _thinks_ the grid should be...it won't know that you've removed bits of it (or even if it does, it's likely to re-draw them again).

Comment: P.S. I agree with mplungjan that removing entire bits from your calendar arbitrarily (and, it sounds like, different bits every time you show the calendar, depending on the available events), is going to create a very confusing user experience. A calendar grid should have a predictable layout, so a user can glance at it an immediately understand events' proximity to each other in time, based on the physical distance between them on the page / screen.

Comment: If you just want a basic list of events on each day, without time-related spacing between them, then you could use the dayGrid view instead of timeGrid - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/daygrid-view and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/daygrid-view-demo